# Build vs Deploy vs Publish (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets

I'm a newbie to J2ee though not a complete newbie. I'm unable to find a good resource (book or video) that could help me understand what ***exactly*** happens when we build, deploy and publish. I have a fair idea though. So my questions are -

1. Is there a good resource out there that can help me understand these concepts? I've read some books on struts and servlets/jsp but they don't delve into eclipse and how/what it does. The eclipse documentation has been helpful but only slightly.
2. When we build an application the the java files are converted into the class files and stored in the java build path. What else happens during build? Many people use the term 'library dependencies', what does this mean? Also, when people refer to dependencies do they refer to files like xml and tld?
3. At what stage (build or run on server) does the container check to see if the dependencies are alright? Say for instance, if the servlet class/name in the web.xml file.
4. Is it appropriate to say that build is basically compilation while deploying the project and running it is the same as executing it?

Comment: At least the first question?

Answer (score 2):

Familiarity with the [servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) would help you (perhaps some older version would be quicker to read like [2.4](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.4-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/)), but general understanding of *what* you build and *how* you do it in Eclipse is what you are after.

The way I see it is that during the build Eclipse creates almost complete version of WAR (or some other archive, if you use EJBs for instance) and by publishing you deploy it to some server (this is practically the same thing although Eclipse might just configure the server to use exploded WAR that it just prepared instead of copying it to some "deploy" dir that you are supposed to do if you work without an IDE).
If you configure your project well, the build can only mean compilation, but if you have more ceremony in it, then some source generation and moving files around might happen too.

To address your second question, library dependencies can be files that reside in `WEB-INF/lib` for instance. Read the spec to know what should be there and what should not. Eclipse tries to copy there all defined dependencies of your project.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. But it doesn't answer most of my question. I too have a sort of idea of the things that happen but I want to be crystal clear with my concepts especially since every application does require a build, deploy and publish. I hope some others can pitch in and help me out. Answering Q1 alone will help me clear all my doubts.

Comment: I'm going to be working on Web Projects Michal. EJB maybe later but for now JDBC is what I'll be using for the database side.

Comment: So you can narrow your investigation to Eclipse WTP Project. There is a [book on WTP](http://www.eclipsewtp.org/), but I think it is outdated now. One source of information would be [WTP wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Category:Eclipse_Web_Tools_Platform_Project). Possibly [Maven integration with WTP](https://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP) can enlighten you too. Apart from that there are tools like IBM RAD that are based on WTP. Their docs should contain a great deal of information about the way WTP works, but I have never read them.

Comment: Thanks for the book recommendation Michal. Since it is specifically titled Eclipse and Web Development I feel it would be useful. Also, I think Maven or Ant is what I'll learn next since they're specifically build tools which can help me clear some of my doubts relating to the build process. Seen through the IBM RAD help docs but seem to be very average. But the book, if I can lay my hands on it, will definitely be of some help. Hopefully! Thanks.